# Json objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array with many JSON objects.

I want to push new row into one JSON object but JavaScript pushes the row to all JSONs in array how can I fix it or can I use something else rather than array?

My code is like this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jsonArray.push(jsonPassengerList);
 }
 jsonArray[0].push({
     "ID":0,
     "Name":"aa",
     "LastName":"",
     "Nationality":"",
     "QuoteType":"",
     "Title":"",
     "Age":0
});
```

How can I fix this or how can I handle multiple JSON objects?

Comment: What is your expected end result? I don't get it

Comment: Side note (again). There's no such thing as "JSON Object". That said - huh?

Comment: I tried to format your question, but I still do not understand it

Comment: What is `jsonPassengerList`? ...And why do you push it to and array (I assume), **5** times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the answers i solve that problem with multi dimesion json

```
var jsonAll="[";

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jsonAll+=""+JSON.stringify(jsonPassengerList)+",";

if(...)
{
    jsonAll=jsonAll.substring(0, jsonAll.length - 2);
    jsonAll+=",{\"ID\": 0, \"Name\": \"\", \"LastName\": \"\", \"Title\": \"\", \"Nationality\": \"\", \"Age\": 0, \"QuoteType\": \"\"}";
    jsonAll+="],";
}

}


    jsonAll=jsonAll.substring(0, jsonAll.length - 1);
    jsonAll+="]";

    var JsonData=JSON.parse(jsonAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you mean. if you have one object like this:

```
var obj1=   {
         "ID":0,
         "Name":"aa",
         "LastName":"",
         "Nationality":"",
         "QuoteType":"",
         "Title":"",
         "Age":0
    }
```

In order to add this object to an array you can do this:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are a little confused on the terminology. Those are regular old javascript objects. Google JSON for more information on that.
2. It looks like from your code snippet you are adding the same object (jsonPassengerList) to your array five times, instead of five different objects once. So, its not updating all five objects, its updating just the one. Which you have referenced five times.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that every objects stored in the `jsonArray` object are in fact the same `jsonPassengerList` object.

If you want independent lists, you have to use a new array instance for every lists stored within `jsonArray`. By the way, `jsonArray` is quite confusing, I would rather call the variable `passengerListStore` or something similar.
    var passengerListStore = [];

```
//initialize empty lists    
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    passengerListStore.push([]);
}


 //push a new passenger into the first passenger list
 passengerListStore[0].push({
     "ID":0,
     "Name":"aa",
     "LastName":"",
     "Nationality":"",
     "QuoteType":"",
     "Title":"",
     "Age":0
});
```